# How to create an instance of an extended class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, extends

I have a class named `Item`. It has the following parameters:
`User owner`, `Category category` and `String description`.

Next to that, I have a subclass named `Painting` which extends the Item-class. A `Painting` has two parameters: `title` and `painter`.

At some point in the code, I'd like to create a `Painting` object. It should be possible to run code from a test file that goes like this:

```
User u1 = new User ("test@test.com");
Category cat = new Category("cat2");
Item painting = sellerMgr.offerPainting(u1, cat, "Selfportret", "Rembrandt");
```

There should be code in the class `sellerMgr` which should be able to register (create) that item (as a Painting), so I can use it in a database for example. How do I call that code exactly? I get confused whenever or not to create a new `Item` or a new `Painting`, and which parameters to add in the creation code.

Comment: What have you tried in your `offerPainting` method? It sounds like you already have the right idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a new class

```
public class Painting extends Item
```

you'll want a constructor that provides two new parameters, String title, User painter

```
public Painting(User owner, Category category, String description, String title, User painter){
    super(owner, category, description);
    this.title = title;
    this.painter = painter
}
```

Whenever you want a new instance of a Painter you can call this method that will set up any of the Item variables for you, while introducing the two new parameters you desire. A call could look like either

```
Item paintingAsItem = new Painting(u1, cat, "desc", "Selfportret", "Rembrandt"); //Generic
Painting painting = new Paining(u1, cat, "desc", "Selfportret", "Rembrandt");
```

Comment: The part I forgot was to put the Item-parameters in the constructor of the Painting. I was already wondering how to get the values of those parameters into Item through creating a Painting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something like this:

```
Painting p = new Painting(u1, cat, title, painter);
```

Assuming your class definition is like this:

```
public class Painting extends Item {

  private String title;
  private String painter;

  public Painting(User owner, Category category, String title, String painter){
    super(owner, category);
    this.title = title;
    this.painter = painter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Painting` constructor should take `Category` and `User` as arguments and should pass them to `super` which calls the constructor of 'Item'.

Like:

`public Painting(User user, Category category) {
       super(user, category);
         ...

}`

Answer (score 0):

In this case sellerMgr.offerPainting should create and return an object of type Painting.  Painting can be cast to an Item, but for the most part you should be using the extending class, which will have more functionality than Item.